# Recycler Adapter reads data again and again after on click item (ANDROID KOTLIN)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

> when i click recycler item it move to new fragment but when come back
> to recycler items their number get doubled.how can i solve this issue
> so it only pass item only one time and item not get doubled.using addOSnapshoListner also has no effect

thanks in advance

Code where adapter attached

```
private var db =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private lateinit var userrecycler : RecyclerView
var list = ArrayList<daxhboard_gridlayout_data>()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_screen, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    if (list.isEmpty()){
    getUserdata()
    userrecycler = dashboard_grid_recycleView.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_grid_recycleView)
    dashboard_grid_recycleView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.requireContext(), 2)
    dashboard_grid_recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)}}`

private fun getUserdata(){
    db.collection("services")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {

                val imgurl = document.data["imageResource"].toString()
                val text = document.data["text1"].toString()

                list.add(daxhboard_gridlayout_data(imgurl,text))
                dashboard_grid_recycleView.adapter = dashboard_gridlayout_adapter(list)
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e("serf", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
}`
```

> Adapter code

```
class dashboard_gridlayout_adapter(private val sampledata: ArrayList<daxhboard_gridlayout_data>): 
Adapter<dashboard_gridlayout_adapter.dashboard_viewholder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): dashboard_viewholder {
    val itemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_gridlayout_single_item_design, parent, 
false)
    return dashboard_viewholder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: dashboard_viewholder, position: Int) {
    val currentitem = sampledata[position]

    Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(currentitem.imageResource)
        .into(holder.imageView)


    holder.textView.text = currentitem.text1
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
        appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.Activity_frag_container, service_providers_list())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
}

override fun getItemCount()=sampledata.size

class dashboard_viewholder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.dashboard_adapter_image
    val textView: TextView = itemView.dashboard_adapter_text
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the list before adding items to it.
Just add the list.clear() line, and it should work.

```
private fun getUserdata(){
    db.collection("services")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            list.clear()
            for (document in documents) {

                val imgurl = document.data["imageResource"].toString()
                val text = document.data["text1"].toString()

                list.add(daxhboard_gridlayout_data(imgurl,text))
                dashboard_grid_recycleView.adapter = dashboard_gridlayout_adapter(list)
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e("serf", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
}
```

I also recomend you take a look at the lifecycle of fragments.

Comment: `list.clear()` line at the beginning of `OnSuccessListener` is crucial in here

Answer (score 0):

it worked if i remove list.empty() condition form where adapter code is attached and use list.clear() inside OnSuccessListner it works